# Cursor implementation in NDB Model not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

### DB Model

Hi,
Need advice on how to use cursor functions in NDB model.I am able to use with_cursor in DB model but its not available in NDB model:

### DB Model

```
       def myDBfn(self):                       
             cursor_from_url = self.request.get('cursor')            
             logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))             
             process_date = util_misc.get_start_date_from_day_param(self)            
             gql_query_text = 'Select * From DummyTable' 
            #Execute query
            query_o = db.GqlQuery(gql_query_text, process_date)            

            if cursor_from_url:                
                query_o.with_cursor(cursor_from_url)                
                BATCH_SIZE = 500
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)
            else:                
                BATCH_SIZE = 1                
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)

            if not results:
                logging.info("pref_email_update_task: all done")
                return                     

            logging.info("Exiting myDBfn....")
        return
```

### NDB Model

```
        def myNDBfn(self):          
            cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('cursor'))                                
            logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))                            

            gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' #Define query conditions here            

            #Execute query            
            query_o = ndb.gql(gql_query_text)            
            if cursor_from_url:       
                query_o.fetch_page(5,start_cursor=cursor_from_url)                
                BATCH_SIZE = 500
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)
            else:                                
                BATCH_SIZE = 1             
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)

            if not results:
                logging.info("feed_sequence_update_second_task: all done")
                return                     
            logging.info("result is {}".format(results))   
            logging.info("Exiting myNDBfn....")
        return
```

But in NDB model this cursor_from_url is giving an error:**raise datastore_errors.BadValueError('invalid cursor')**
 Kindly advice!!!!!

Comment: Hi there. Are you using the Python 2 NDB Client Library by any chance? If so, this solution is no longer recommended, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb). You will most likely need to [migrate to Cloud NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb).

Comment: Yes i am using python 2.7. i need a solution in the existing NDB model as our system uses this model extensively. May be the mirgation can be done afterwards. Any idea about the fix?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix but not sure if it is the right way of using cursor in NDB Model:
            def feed_sequence_update_alltime(self):

```
            logging.info("In feed_sequence_update_alltime")           
            cursor_from_url = ndb.Cursor.from_websafe_string(self.request.get('cursor'))                      
            logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))                              

            gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' #Define query conditions here            

            #Execute query            
            query_o = ndb.gql(gql_query_text)            

            if cursor_from_url:
                query_o.fetch_page(20)                                                          
                BATCH_SIZE = 500
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)                                                
            else:                                                
                BATCH_SIZE = 1              
                results = query_o.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)                

            if not results:
                logging.info("feed_sequence_update_task: all done")
                return

            logging.info("result is {}".format(results))

            #Calling fn to insert data in FeedSequence
            record_type = 'alltime'
            FeedModelCheck.add_feeds_sequences_records(self,results,record_type)

            cursor = query_o.fetch()
            taskqueue.add(url='/admin/feed/add-top-searches-alltime', params={'cursor': cursor})

            logging.info("Exiting feed_sequence_update_alltime")
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I rewrote my answer, because i misread your code.

You were constructing the Cursor correctly in the first place. The issue is that you were ignoring the results of `fetch_page()`

I rewrote your function

```
    def myNDBfn(self):
        urlsafe_cursor = self.request.get('cursor', None)
        cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=urlsafe_cursor) if urlsafe_cursor else None                      
        logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))                            

        gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' #Define query conditions here            

        #Execute query
        results, next_cursor, more = ndb.gql(gql_query_text).fetch_page(500, start_cursor=cursor_from_url)            

        if not results:
            logging.info("feed_sequence_update_second_task: all done")
            return                     
        logging.info("result is {}".format(results))  
        logging.info("next cursor is {}. urlsafe: {}".format(next_cursor, next_cursor.urlsafe()))   
        logging.info("Exiting myNDBfn....")
    return
```

Comment: So what i understand from your code fix. i need to do this:-               
            if cursor_from_url:
            BATCH_SIZE = 500
            results, next_cursor, more =  query_o.fetch_page(BATCH_SIZE,start_cursor = cursor_object )            
            else:
                None                
            if more:
                next_cursor.urlsafe()                                              Is this correct?

Comment: I rewrote my answer, because i misread your code. See my changes above where i rewrote `myNDBfn`

Comment: Thanks the code is working. But in the logs i am getting the error for cursor:INFO     2020-04-30 04:09:28,559 feed_model_chk.py:163] Cursor in start is:  
WARNING  2020-04-30 04:09:28,559 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator     ERROR    2020-04-30 04:09:28,559 webapp2.py:1552] invalid cursor_fetch_page_async(query.py:1380) raised BadValueError(invalid cursor)

ERROR    2020-04-30 04:09:28,559 webapp2.py:1552] invalid cursor

Comment: did the cursor not get printed when you did `logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))  `?

Comment: Nope. its coming blank

Comment: can you also print out `urlsafe_cursor`? where are you getting your cursor from initially?

Comment: cursor_from_url in start is: Cursor(<TestSequenceskeyKeyTestSequencesseqid_1deletedTrueseq_accessupublicseq_cues=>)
INFO     2020-05-02 06:24:38,415 feed_model_chk.py:164] urlsafe_cursor in start is: TestSequences(key=Key('TestSequences', 'seqid_1'), deleted=True, seq_access=u'public', seq_cues=u'cue1', seq_desc=u'demo1', seq_duration=150, seq_focus=u'focus1', seq_level=u'level_1', seq_local_id=u'L1', seq_playlist=u's10', seq_poses=[u'pose1', u'pose2', u'pose3', u'pose4'], seq_poses_breath_count=u'100', seq_poses_breath_type=u'normal', seq_poses_custom=u'pose_c1', seq_pose........

Comment: `urlsafe_cursor` is a base64 encoded string and should look like this: `ClAKFAoHY3JlYXRlZBIJCJSmreqjmukCEjRqD3N-cGF5LXRvbGxvLXdlYnIhCxIUUGF5bWVudFJlcXVlc3RSZXN1bHQYgICgwariigkMGAAgAQ%3D%3D` you get it by calling `.urlsafe()` on the previous cursor. Where did it come from?

Comment: its coming from TestSequence directory which i am populating first...

Comment: You mean the data inside url? it comes from TestSequence model

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the final code i am using.Please have a look if i am using the taskqueue correctly?  
  def myNDBfn(self):
            logging.info("Entering myNDBfn...")
            urlsafe_cursor = self.request.get('cursor', None)
            cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=urlsafe_cursor) if urlsafe_cursor else None                      
            logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))                            

            gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' #Define query conditions here 
            #Execute query                        
            query_o = ndb.gql(gql_query_text)
            BATCH_SIZE = 500
            results, next_cursor, more = query_o.fetch_page(BATCH_SIZE, start_cursor=cursor_from_url)

            if more:
               pass
            if next_cursor:
               pass

            if not results:
               logging.info("feed_sequence_update_second_task: all done")
               return

            logging.info(" results is {}".format(results))

            #Calling fn to insert data in FeedSequence
            record_type = 'daily'
            FeedModelCheck.add_feeds_sequences_records(self,results,record_type)      

            cursor = query_o.fetch()
            taskqueue.add(url='/admin/feed/add-top-searches-daily', params={'cursor': cursor})         
            logging.info("Exiting myNDBfn...")
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from models.feed_models import TestSequences, FeedsSequences
from controllers.system import template, error as err, security as sec
from collections import defaultdict
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import Cursor

class FeedModelCheck(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        get_methods = {
                    '/admin/feed/test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records': 'test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records',
                    '/admin/feed/add-top-searches-daily' : 'feed_sequence_update_daily',
                    '/admin/feed/add-top-searches-alltime' : 'feed_sequence_update_alltime',
                      }

```
    post_methods = {                                               
                    '/admin/feed/add-top-searches-alltime' : 'feed_sequence_update_alltime',
                    '/admin/feed/add-top-searches-daily' : 'feed_sequence_update_daily'
                   }

    # Methods Definitions  
    def __init__(self, request='', response=''):
        super(FeedModelCheck, self).__init__(request, response)
        self.request = request
        self.response = response
        self.GETSTR = 'get'
        self.POSTSTR = 'post'
        return 

    def get(self):
        logging.info('In get method')
        self.process_url(self.GETSTR)
        return

    def post(self):
        logging.info('In Post method')
        self.process_url(self.POSTSTR)
        return

    def process_url(self, source):
        #validate URL
        rcvd_url = self.request.path
        logging.info('Rcvd url = %s', rcvd_url)            
        if source == self.GETSTR:
            func_map = self.get_methods
        else:
            func_map = self.post_methods

        secObj = sec.SecurityHandler()
        if secObj.validate_url(rcvd_url):
            #get destination method using key-value pair
            dest_method = func_map.get(rcvd_url, None) # Correction 2
            logging.info("dest_method is {}".format(dest_method))
            if dest_method:
                func = getattr(self, dest_method, None)
                logging.info("func is {}".format(func))
                if func:
                    func()
                    logging.info('Finished %s method', source)        
                    return
        #Invalid url
        else:
            pass #case handled below  

        #Invalid URL
        err_obj = err.ErrorHandler()
        err_obj.handle_invalid_url(rcvd_url)
        self.error(404)
        logging.info('Finished %s method with error', source)        
        return      

    def test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records(self):
        #In this function, create 10-15 dummy records in TestSequences database for testing purposes
        logging.info("In test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records")

        ## LOGIC GOES HERE ##
        key_seq_list = ["seqid_1","seqid_2","seqid_3", "seqid_4"]
        user_email_list = ["abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","efg@gmail.com","pqr@gmail.com"]
        user_type_list = ["teacher","intraining","therapist","teacher"]
        seq_poses_list = [["pose1","pose2","pose3","pose4"],["pose5","pose6","pose7","pose8"],["pose9","pose10","pose11","pose12"],["pose13","pose14","pose15","pose16"]]
        seq_poses_custom_list = ["pose_c1","pose_c2","pose_c3","pose_c4"]
        seq_poses_num_list = [1,2,3,4]
        seq_poses_breath_count_list = ["100","200","300","400"]
        seq_poses_breath_type_list = ["normal","high","low","normal"]
        seq_poses_duration_list = ["10 seconds","20 seconds","30 seconds","10 seconds"]
        seq_poses_renames_list = ["1","2","3","4"]
        seq_cues_list = ["cue1","cue2","cue3","cue4"]
        seq_title_list = ["seq_1","seq_2","seq_3","seq_4"]
        seq_desc_list = ["demo1","demo2","demo3","demo4"]
        seq_tags_list = [["tag1"],["tag2"],["tag3"],["tag4"]]
        seq_level_list = ["level_1","level_2","level_3","level_4"]
        seq_theme_list = ["theme1","theme2","theme3","theme4"]
        seq_focus_list = ["focus1","focus2","focus3","focus4"]
        seq_props_list = [["props1"],["props2"],["props3"],["props4"]]
        seq_props_other_list = ["props_others1","props_others2","props_others3","props_others4"]
        seq_access_list = ["public","private","public","private"]
        seq_duration_list = [150,250,360,450]
        seq_playlist_list = ["s10","s20","s30","s40"]
        seq_local_id_list = ["L1","L2","L1","L2"]
        seq_source_seq_id_list = ["0001","0002","0003","0004"]
        seq_source_seq_type_list = ["self","teacher","tummee","merged"]
        seq_yoga_type_list = ["yoga_type_a","yoga_type_a","yoga_type_a","yoga_type_b"]            
        deleted_list = [True,False,True,False]            

        i = 0
        for key_item in key_seq_list:
            #Use get_or_inser to fetch function to check data presence in TestSequences Model.
            test_sequence = TestSequences.get_or_insert(key_item, user_email= user_email_list[i],user_type = user_type_list[i],seq_poses=seq_poses_list[i],seq_poses_custom = seq_poses_custom_list[i],seq_poses_num = seq_poses_num_list[i],seq_poses_breath_count = seq_poses_breath_count_list[i],seq_poses_breath_type = seq_poses_breath_type_list[i],seq_poses_duration = seq_poses_duration_list[i],seq_poses_renames = seq_poses_renames_list[i],seq_cues = seq_cues_list[i],seq_title = seq_title_list[i],seq_desc = seq_desc_list[i],seq_tags = seq_tags_list[i],seq_level = seq_level_list[i],seq_theme = seq_theme_list[i],seq_focus = seq_focus_list[i],seq_props = seq_props_list[i],seq_props_other = seq_props_other_list[i],seq_access = seq_access_list[i],seq_duration = seq_duration_list[i],seq_playlist = seq_playlist_list[i],seq_local_id = seq_local_id_list[i],seq_source_seq_id = seq_source_seq_id_list[i],seq_source_seq_type = seq_source_seq_type_list[i],seq_yoga_type = seq_yoga_type_list[i],deleted = deleted_list[i])                
            #Use put() in a for loop to insert data in TestSequences Model.
            test_sequence.put()                                
            if (i < (len(key_seq_list)-1)):                    
                i+=1                

        logging.info("Exiting test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records")
        return        

    def feed_sequence_update_alltime(self):

        logging.info("In feed_sequence_update_alltime")          
        urlsafe_cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=urlsafe_cursor) if urlsafe_cursor else None                                                                  
        logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))                                        

        #Define query here
        gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' 

        #Execute query                        
        query_o = ndb.gql(gql_query_text)
        BATCH_SIZE = 500
        results, next_cursor, more = query_o.fetch_page(BATCH_SIZE, start_cursor=cursor_from_url)

        if more:
            pass
        if next_cursor:
            pass            

        if not results:
            logging.info("feed_sequence_update_task: all done")
            return


        #Calling fn to insert data in FeedSequence            
        record_type = 'alltime'
        FeedModelCheck.add_feeds_sequences_records(self,results,record_type)

        cursor = query_o.fetch()
        taskqueue.add(url='/admin/feed/add-top-searches-alltime', params={'cursor': cursor})            
        logging.info("Exiting feed_sequence_update_alltime")
        return

    def feed_sequence_update_daily(self):

        logging.info("In feed_sequence_update_daily")             
        urlsafe_cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=urlsafe_cursor) if urlsafe_cursor else None                                                                  
        logging.info("cursor_from_url in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))
        logging.info("urlsafe_cursor in start is: {}".format(urlsafe_cursor))                                       

        #Define query here
        gql_query_text = 'Select * From TestSequences' 

        #Execute query                        
        query_o = ndb.gql(gql_query_text)
        BATCH_SIZE = 500
        results, next_cursor, more = query_o.fetch_page(BATCH_SIZE, start_cursor=cursor_from_url)

        if more:
            pass
        if next_cursor:
            pass

        if not results:
            logging.info("feed_sequence_update_second_task: all done")
            return                     
        logging.info(" results is {}".format(results))

        #Calling fn to insert data in FeedSequence
        record_type = 'daily'
        FeedModelCheck.add_feeds_sequences_records(self,results,record_type)      

        cursor = query_o.fetch()
        taskqueue.add(url='/admin/feed/add-top-searches-daily', params={'cursor': cursor})            

        logging.info("Exiting feed_sequence_update_daily")
        return

    def add_feeds_sequences_records(self,results,rec_type):

        logging.info("Entering add_feeds_sequences_records...")

        ## LOGIC TO RUN FOR LOOP AND PUT DATA IN FeedsSequences database ##            
        seq_yoga_list = []
        seq_id_list = []
        for record in results:
            seq_yoga_list = seq_yoga_list + list(str(record.seq_yoga_type).split())                
            seq_id_list = seq_id_list + list(str(record.key.id()).split())

        #yoga_type and corresponding seq_id are associated with each other as key, value pair in a dictionary
        dict_result = defaultdict(list)                                
        for k, v in zip(seq_yoga_list, seq_id_list):
            dict_result[k].append(v)            

        for record in results:                      
            sequence_key = record.seq_yoga_type
            record_type = rec_type                             
            feed_seq = FeedsSequences.get_or_insert(sequence_key,record_type=record_type,sequence_list=dict_result[record.seq_yoga_type])                 
            feed_seq.put()

        logging.info("Exiting for add_feeds_sequences_records...")               
        return
```

app = template.webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/admin/feed/test_create_dummy_TestSequences_records', FeedModelCheck),
    ('/admin/feed/add-top-searches-alltime', FeedModelCheck),
    ('/admin/feed/add-top-searches-daily', FeedModelCheck),
    ], debug=True)